# Can't import backup from postgres to different server with the same version of postgres because of different monetary format

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgresql-9.1, pg-restore

I'm moving my databases from Postgres 9.1.23 running on Debian 7.11 to a different server with Postgres 9.1.24 running on Debian 10 and I can't import one database that's using money data type because I get input syntax error

```
COPY failed for table "x": ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type money: "zł4.400,00"
```

I'm using the same locale on both Postgres servers, on Debian 7.11:

```
postgres=# show lc_collate;
 lc_collate
-------------
 pl_PL.UTF-8
(1 row)

postgres=# show lc_monetary;
 lc_monetary
-------------
 pl_PL.UTF-8
(1 row)
```

And on Debian 10:

```
postgres=# show lc_collate;
 lc_collate
-------------
 pl_PL.UTF-8
(1 wiersz)

postgres=# show lc_monetary;
 lc_monetary
-------------
 pl_PL.UTF-8
(1 wiersz)
```

Yet when I try to run `select '12345'::money;` on both servers I get different results, on Debian 7.11:

```
postgres=# select '12345'::money;
    money
-------------
 zł12.345,00
(1 row)
```

and on Debian 10:

```
postgres=# select '12345'::money;
    money
-------------
 zł12 345,00
(1 wiersz)
```

(in Debian 10 between 2 and 3 there is a narrow no-brake space character - 0x202F UTF-16)

What do I have to successfully import it without errors? Thank you for help.

Comment: You [shouldn't](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) be using the money type to begin with. I guess the best option would be to change those columns to `numeric` before exporting them.  I wouldn't be surprised if that is another incarnation of the [locale data changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) between operating systems

Comment: Thank you! I think that worked fine, first I created a copy of the database on Debian 7, altered that column to use `numeric`, dumped it, restored it on Debian 10 and then changed column type back to `money`.

Comment: You should stick to the numeric type and get rid of `money` completely. You should also plan an upgrade to a supported Postgres version as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm not the author of code that uses this db, so I don't know If I can change this column type to numeric without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be that the GNU C library must have changed its idea of `LC_MONETARY` between these versions.

I would dump and restore using the C locale:

```sh
PGOPTIONS='-c lc_monetary=C' pg_dump -F c -f dumpfile dbname
PGOPTIONS='-c lc_monetary=C' pg_restore -d newdbname dumpfile
```